# Replacing single quote from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string with contain some single quote, I want to replace all the single quote present inside string with double quote excluding the single quote preset inside {} [] () . Any pointer will be really helpful trying to solve this using JAVASCRIPT.

Actual String :

```
let str =`name:'John' {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')`;
console.log(str);
```

Expected Output:

> name:"John" {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')

Comment: What's the point of changing it? The type of quote doesn't affect your output (unless I misunderstood you).

Comment: We are using a third party lib which  expect input in this particular format , because of which are working on replacing it

Comment: That data structure makes no sense though. You would expect a comma between `name:'John'` and `{hobbies:'Playing'}` too.

Comment: You are better off changing whatever produces this mess. It is not JSON, it is not valid js it is really ugly. Can you change the provider to return `{"name":"John","hobbies":["Playing","Acting"],"age":45}` instead?

Comment: @mplungjan Reread the comment `...because of which are working on replacing it`. They just need a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

In order to replace just the single quotes around `John`, you'll probably want to use a bit of Regex.

```js
let str = "name:'John' {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')";
str = str.replaceAll(/(name:)'([^']+?)'/g, "$1\"$2\"");
console.log(str);
//    name:"John" {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')
```

Comment: It will replace all the single quote , I want to exclude single quote present inside [] () {}

Comment: Just updated to meet that requirement. My mistake on the first edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `str.replaceAll("'", '"');`

Comment: It will replace all the single quote , I want to exclude single quote present inside [] () {}

Answer (score 0):

```
let braceTracker = 0;

// convert string into an array of string using spread operator
// alternatively you can do str.split("")
let str = [..."name:'John' {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')"];

for (let x = 0; x < str.length; x++)
{
    if(str[x] === "[" || str[x] === "{" || str[x] === "(")
        braceTracker++;
    else if(str[x] === "]" || str[x] === "}" || str[x] === ")")
        braceTracker--;
    else if(str[x] === "'" && braceTracker === 0)
        str[x] = "\"";
}

console.log(str.join(""));

// output :   name:"John" {hobbies:'Playing'} , (age: '45')
```